# Is it possible to write all metasploit command in a text file and run it?

Tags: metasploit

I wonder, is it possible to load a command text file with metasploit? for example if I want to use a scanner module I can just write all the command in a text file and run it with the metasploit, so I won't have to fill most prompts

Comment: There are other ways to control Metasploit without using it interactively, such as by using the RPC API.

Comment: Check the following project on GitHub that might help you : https://github.com/darkoperator/Metasploit-Plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts, in general, will run a command and wait for it to execute. Only once the process launched by the command finishes will your script move on to the next command.
metasploit can be used in interactive mode, and that seems to be what you're trying to do. That means the msfconsole is the process that's created and so the script won't continue until that process terminates.

You could look at using something like expect to interact with a program that expects input while it's running. Alternately, many things you want to do in metasploit can be done without an interactive session so you could try to find those sets of commands and use them instead.

or you could do that using a language like ruby or python, [here](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/auxiliary/admin/serverprotect/file.rb) is a ruby script exemple made by rapid7 the developpers of the metasploit framework.

Hope it helps.